# Type in Ruta Script can't be resolved when script is called from a pipeline

Tags: type-systems, uima, ruta

I try to build a pipeline that incorporates a Ruta script.

I use Uima.CollectionReader to read the text in, and an xmi-writer to write out the result. I call my analysis engines with SimplePipeline.runPipeline, and that works fine, as long as the ruta script is not incorporated.

The Ruta script for itself also works fine and produces the desired output. But when I use the script in the pipeline I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not able to resolve type: Unsinn
at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.type.SimpleTypeExpression.getType(SimpleTypeExpression.java:47)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.action.AbstractMarkAction.createAnnotation(AbstractMarkAction.java:42)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.action.MarkAction.execute(MarkAction.java:57)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.AbstractRuleElement.apply(AbstractRuleElement.java:130)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RuleElementCaretaker.applyRuleElements(RuleElementCaretaker.java:111)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.applyRuleElements(ComposedRuleElement.java:593)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.AbstractRuleElement.doneMatching(AbstractRuleElement.java:84)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallback(ComposedRuleElement.java:514)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:415)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.startMatch(RutaRuleElement.java:102)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.startMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:74)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:47)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:40)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:29)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaScriptBlock.apply(RutaScriptBlock.java:63)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaModule.apply(RutaModule.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:545)
```

I give a full path to TypeSystem where the type -- in this case "Unsinn" -- is described, but that doesn't help.

```
    AnalysisEngineDescription ruta =
                    AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(
                            RutaEngine.class,
                            RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "Test",
                            RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_PATHS, "C:/Users/some.user/workspace/Test_Ruta/script/test/",
                            RutaEngine.PARAM_DESCRIPTOR_PATHS, "C:/Users/some.user/workspace/Test_Ruta/descriptor/",
                            RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8"
                            );
```

I'm new to Uima and also to Stackoverflow, but I'm already pretty desperate. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that Ruta is not able to resolve an actual type given the short name "Unsinn". Depending on the configuration parameters, this can have two reasons. In your case, I assume that the type is not present in the type system of the CAS/JCas. The configuration parameter of the RutaEngine does not affect the type system at all. You need to take care that the type system is included in the CAS when it is created, in your case in the collection reader.

I assume that you use uimaFIT for creating the reader and analysis engine (descriptions)? Then, you can simply add the type system containing "Unsinn" in the types.txt file of uimaFIT so that the type system is collected during the classpath scan.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*